# Unable to send web requests to remote server

Tags: elm

I receive the following error when I attempt to make a web request to a recently deployed remote server that's shared and running IIS:

> SEC7120: Origin http://localhost:8000 not found in
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
>
> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
>   requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). (XHR)GET -
>   http://mywebsite/someservice/somevalue

All of this works fine when I run the web server on my local machine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set up CORS handling on the server so that browsers will allow cross-origin javascript requests. See [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests (CORS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors) for instructions on how to do this for .Net Core apps.